# How to get lazy evaluation of files in java as DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles() method of IEnumerable in C#

Tags: c#, java

In C# when you use DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles() method of IEnumerable interface, you can start enumerating the collection of names before the whole collection is returned.How to get this in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Java 7 you can't, as far as I'm aware. [`File.listFiles()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) is what you've got, basically - with an overload to take a `FileFilter` of course.

Java 7 has a new file system API, including [`FileVisitor<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) which may be what you're after. It's not *quite* the same as having a sequence of files which you can access lazily, but it may do what you need. You'd probably want to create a subclass of [`SimpleFileVisitor<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/SimpleFileVisitor.html).

Comment: I am new to java.I have task to read heavy amount of files from certain directory.I know about .Enumerate() method in C# according to my requirement.But i have to do this in java.

Comment: @urzshah: Well, I've explained your options here... it's not clear what else you're looking for, especially as we don't know whether you can use Java 7 or not.

Comment: thnx..I am able to find my solution.